# Is it possible to use a derived type variable with the shared attribute inside an OpenMP parallel region?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am running a Fortran code (compiled with Intel Fortran) that has an OpenMp parallel region within which I would like to have access to data that is stored in a derived type vector (whis has allocatable fields of different types).

Each thread will only work with one position in this vector so therefore I would like the vector to have the "shared" attribute.

When running the code I get some strange errors and therefore I wonder is it possible to use a derived type vector in this way?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there's no problem with using derived types:

```
program derivedtype
   use omp_lib
   implicit none

   integer, parameter :: sz=20

   type mytype1
       integer, dimension(sz) :: a
       real   , dimension(sz) :: b
   end type mytype1

   type mytype2
       integer :: a
       real    :: b
   end type mytype2

   type(mytype1) :: var1
   type(mytype2), dimension(sz) :: var2
   integer:: i
   integer:: isum
   real   :: rsum

   var1%a = 2
   var1%b = 1.
   forall (i=1:sz)
       var2(i)%a = 3
       var2(i)%b = 4.
   endforall

   isum = 0
   rsum = 0.
   print *, var1%a
   print *, var1%b
   print *, [(var2(i)%a, i=1,sz)]
   print *, [(var2(i)%b, i=1,sz)]

!$omp parallel do default(none) shared(var1,var2), reduction(+:rsum), reduction(+:isum)
   do i=1,sz
      isum = isum + var1%a(i) + var2(i)%a
      rsum = rsum + var1%b(i) + var2(i)%b
   enddo

   print *,'isum = ', isum
   print *,'rsum = ', rsum
end program derivedtype
```

The problem probably has something to do with the allocatable parts, and that's a little more subtle; OpenMP3.0 didn't really deal with derived types with allocatable components, and it's not clear to me what, if anything, 3.1 says about the matter.   But even apart from that, there's ways that you can go wrong with allocatables in OpenMP -- same problems occur with C and pointers.  Can you give us an example of what exactly fails?